# Find value of $g(x)$ where it is the inverse of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

Find $g′\left(-\dfrac{1}{9}\right)$, where $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)=\dfrac{x^{17}}{(x^2+8)}$.

What is $g\left(-\dfrac{1}{9}\right)$  and $g'\left(-\dfrac{1}{9}\right)$?

I tried setting $f(x)=-\dfrac{1}{9}$, but solving that would be far too time consuming. What is the correct way to go about this$?$

Comment: compute f(-1)=-1/9. it's the

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Now since they are inverses of each other we have

a) $f\circ g(x) = x$ and

b) $g\circ f(x) =x$.

Now we have that $f(-1) = -\dfrac{1}{9}$. So from (b) $g(f(-1))=-1$ that is $g\left(-\dfrac{1}{9}\right)=-1$

Also by chain rule of differentiation on (a) we get that $f'(g(x))g'(x)=1$ . So for $x=-\dfrac{1}{9}$ we get $f'(-1)g'\left(-\dfrac{1}{9}\right) =1$.

Can you complete it from here?